# Which networking syscalls cause VM Exits to Hypervisor in Intel VMX?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, virtual-machine, virtualization, hypervisor

I am having trouble understanding which (if any) system calls cause a VM Exit to VMX root-mode under Intel VMX. I am specifically interested in network-related system calls (i.e. socket, accept, send, recv) as they require a "virtual" device. I understand the hypervisor will have to be invoked to actually open a socket, but could this be done in parallel (assuming on a multi-core processor)?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: VMX itself does not define any "syscall" that should trap or cause VM exit to the host. The CPU doesn't even need to know what a syscall is for VMX to work. This is entirely up to the OS to decide. Did you mean to tag this with [linux-kernel] and possibly [linux]? Otherwise this question is kind of ill-formed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I guess I did mean to tag it with linux-kernel and/or linux (which I will do). However, what documentation could I use to determine whether a guest OS would cause a VM exit or not if a network-related syscall occurred?

Comment: For example, I am interested in finding out which (if any) syscalls should trap or cause VM exit to the host for a guest Ubuntu OS on a VMX-capable machine.

Comment: `mmap` might, on an older CPU that doesn't have hardware support for nested page tables. Or yeah, likely anything involving virtual hardware or paravirtualized drivers.  But note that an `open()` or `socket()` system call doesn't send any packets; even `write` doesn't *necessarily* send a packet on a TCP connection, depending on the size of the write vs. MTU.  But `send` probably would, unless you use `MSG_MORE`.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you for the comment. Is it always necessary for a VM Exit to occur (if necessary) to send a packet on the NIC if on a multi-core system and there are available cores that could allow the VMM and a guest to run concurrently? I guess what I'm asking if increased parallelism could prevent VM Exits simply by allowing the hypervisor to run in parallel with a guest. I understand VM Exits can be quite costly compared to typical OS context switches.

Comment: @ballsmahoney ok, now I see what you meant by "in parallel", I've edited my answer to address this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html) (Volume 3, Chapter 22) none of `int 0x80`, `sysenter` and `syscall`, the three main instructions used under Linux to execute a system call, can cause VM exits ***per se***. So in general there isn't a clear-cut way to tell which syscalls cause a VM exit and which ones don't.

VM exits can occur in a lot of scenarios, for example the host can configure an exception bitmap to decide which exceptions cause a VM exit, including page faults, so in theory almost any piece of code doing memory operations (kernel or user) could cause a VM exit.

Excluding such an extreme case and talking specifically about networking, as [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) suggests in the [above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69996355/which-syscalls-cause-vm-exits-to-hypervisor-in-intel-vmx/70004911#comment123740785_69996355), what you should be concerned about are operations that [may] send and receive data, since those will eventually require communication with the hardware (NIC):

- Syscalls like `socket`, `socketpair`, `{get,set}sockopt`, `bind`, `shutdown` (etc.) should not cause VM exits since they do not require communication with the underlying hardware and they merely manipulate logical kernel data structures.
- `read`, `recv` and `write` can cause VM exits unless the kernel already has data available to read or is waiting to accumulate enough data to write (e.g. as per [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm)) before sending. Whether or not the kernel actually stops to read from HW or directly sends to HW depends on socket options, syscall flags and current state of the underlying socket/connection.
- `sendto`, `recvfrom`, `sendmsg`, `recvmsg` (etc.), `select`, `poll`, `epoll` (etc.) on network sockets can all cause VM exits, again depending on the specific situation, pretty much the same reasoning as the previous point.
- `connect` should not need to VM exit for datagram sockets (`SOCK_DGRAM`) as it merely sets a default address, but definitely can for connection-based protocols (e.g. `SOCK_STREAM`) as the kernel needs to send and receive packets to establish a connection.
- `accept` also needs to send/receive data and therefore can cause VM exits.

> I understand the hypervisor will have to be invoked to actually open a socket, but could this be done in parallel (assuming on a multi-core processor)?

"In parallel" is not the term that I would use, but network I/O operations can be handled by the OS asynchronously, e.g. packets are not necessarily received or sent exactly when requested through a syscall, but when needed. For example, one or more VM exits needed to receive data could have already been performed before the guest userspace program issues the relative syscall.

> Is it always necessary for a VM Exit to occur (if necessary) to send a packet on the NIC if on a multi-core system and there are available cores that could allow the VMM and a guest to run concurrently? I guess what I'm asking if increased parallelism could prevent VM Exits simply by allowing the hypervisor to run in parallel with a guest.

When a VM exit occurs the guest CPU is stopped and cannot resume execution until the VMM issues a VMRESUME for it (see Intel SDE Vol 3 Chapter 23.1 "Virtual Machine Control Structures Overview"). It is not possible to "prevent" a VM exit from occurring, however on a multi-processor system the VMM could theoretically run on multiple cores and delegate the handling of a VM exit to another VMM thread while resuming the stopped VM early.

So while increased parallelism cannot prevent VM exits, it could theoretically reduce their overhead. However do note that this can only happen for VM exits that can be handled "lazily" while resuming the guest. As an example, if the guest page-faults and VM-exits, the VMM cannot really "delegate" the handling of the VM exit and resume the guest earlier, since the guest will need the page fault to be resolved before resuming execution.

---

All in all, whenever the guest kernel needs to communicate with hardware, this can be a cause of VM exit. Access to emulated hardware for I/O operations requires the hypervisor to step in and therefore cause VM exits. There are however possible optimizations to consider:

- Hardware passthrough can be used on systems which support [IOMMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input%E2%80%93output_memory_management_unit) to make devices directly available to the guest OS and achieve very low overhead in HW communication with **no need for VM exits**. See [Intel VT-d](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/develop/external/us/en/documents/vt-directed-io-spec.pdf), [Intel VT-c](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/technology-briefs/virtualization-technology-connectivity-brief.pdf), [SR-IOV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-root_input/output_virtualization), and also ["PCI passthrough via OVMF" on ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF).
- **[Virtio](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Virtio)** is a standard for paravirtualization of network (NICs) and block devices (disks) which aims at reducing I/O overhead (i.e. overall number of needed VM exits), but needs support from both guest and host. The guest is "aware" of being a guest in this case. See also: [Virtio for Linux/KVM](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Virtio).

---

Further reading:

- [x86 virtualization - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization)
- [Virtual device passthrough for high speed VM networking - S. Garzarella, G. Lettieri, L. Rizzo](http://info.iet.unipi.it/%7Eluigi/papers/20150315-netmap-passthrough.pdf)
- [virtio: Towards a De-Facto Standard For Virtual I/O Devices - Rusty Russell](https://ozlabs.org/%7Erusty/virtio-spec/virtio-paper.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer Marco. However, I have additional clarification questions if you wouldn't mind expanding on them;

What do you mean by "read, recv or write can cause VM exits unless the kernel already has data available to read"? Since this is handled asynchronously, is it possible the VMM went ahead and modified the VCPU state without inducing VM Exit, and now that the data is available no VM Exit ever has to be performed?

Comment: Additionally, when you say "one or more VM exits needed to receive data could have already been performed before the guest userspace program issues the relative syscall", how could the data (from read/recv for example) already have been read/recv before the explicit syscall? From my understanding technologies such as VT-X and even AMD-V eliminate the need for Binary Translation, so I'm not sure how the VMM (or anyone else) could prematurely know to get this information for the guest beforehand.

Comment: @ballsmahoney in both those instances I simply mean that the kernel could have already received data from the device e.g. through an interrupt or through HW I/O (which both can cause VM exits), and when the actual syscall is made there is no need to do another exit because the data is already ready in a guest kernel buffer, so the guest userspace program issuing the syscall does not cause a VM exit and just gets a copy of the already received data.